# Array sort by datetime not working for new months

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, associative-array

I have an array like this and array sort functions which works well sorting an array based on a key value which is date and time. The function works well if the date time value in all array elements is from the same month. Like i have this array.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 03/02/2017 07:54
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 03/02/2017
        [location] => Coslada (Madrid)-Espanha
        [time] => 07:54
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 03/02/2017 07:52
        [status] => O volume chegou à Plataforma da .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 03/02/2017
        [location] => Coslada (Madrid)-Espanha
        [time] => 07:52
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 16:27
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 16:27
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 16:26
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 16:26
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 20:15
        [status] => Os dados do volume foram introduzidos no sistema .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 20:15
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 00:00
        [status] => Os dados do volume foram introduzidos no sistema \3B o volume ainda não foi entregue à .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 00:00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 19:27
        [status] => Encomenda transferida: Chegará a Italy em breve
        [status_id] => 6
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Portugal
        [time] => 19:27
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 16:25
        [status] => Encomenda recebida pela Delnext. Em preparação para ser enviada.
        [status_id] => 2
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Portugal
        [time] => 16:25
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 29/01/2017 13:17
        [status] => Encomenda em processo de recolha
        [status_id] => 13
        [date] => 29/01/2017
        [location] => Spain
        [time] => 13:17
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 29/01/2017 13:16
        [status] => Pendente
        [status_id] => 1
        [date] => 29/01/2017
        [location] => Spain
        [time] => 13:16
    )

)
```

and here is my function which sorts the array based on datetime value.

```
usort($second_tracking_array, 'date_compare');
function date_compare($a, $b) {

    define('AMERICAN_DATE_FORMAT', 'm/d/Y G:i');
    $a['datetime'] = trim($a['datetime']);
    $b['datetime'] = trim($b['datetime']);
    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat(AMERICAN_DATE_FORMAT, $a['datetime'])->getTimestamp();
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat(AMERICAN_DATE_FORMAT, $b['datetime'])->getTimestamp();
    return $date2 - $date1;
}
```

The function sort the array perfectly if all of same month but if the array contains a datetime from different months. It does not sort well.
Below is the result array after function execution.

```
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 29/01/2017 13:17
        [status] => Encomenda em processo de recolha
        [status_id] => 13
        [date] => 29/01/2017
        [location] => Spain
        [time] => 13:17
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 29/01/2017 13:16
        [status] => Pendente
        [status_id] => 1
        [date] => 29/01/2017
        [location] => Spain
        [time] => 13:16
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 03/02/2017 07:54
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 03/02/2017
        [location] => Coslada (Madrid)-Espanha
        [time] => 07:54
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 03/02/2017 07:52
        [status] => O volume chegou à Plataforma da .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 03/02/2017
        [location] => Coslada (Madrid)-Espanha
        [time] => 07:52
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 19:27
        [status] => Encomenda transferida: Chegará a Italy em breve
        [status_id] => 6
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Portugal
        [time] => 19:27
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 16:27
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 16:27
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 02/02/2017 16:26
        [status] => Volume saiu da plataforma da 
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 02/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 16:26
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 20:15
        [status] => Os dados do volume foram introduzidos no sistema .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 20:15
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 16:25
        [status] => Encomenda recebida pela Delnext. Em preparação para ser enviada.
        [status_id] => 2
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Portugal
        [time] => 16:25
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 01/02/2017 00:00
        [status] => Os dados do volume foram introduzidos no sistema \3B o volume ainda não foi entregue à .
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 01/02/2017
        [location] => Venda do Pinheiro-Portugal
        [time] => 00:00
    )

)
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about 'it does not sort well'. What are your results?

Comment: I update my question with the result array. As you can see that dates from 1st months are sorted first and then the dates of february. But it has to sort the array in most recent one on top.

Comment: Those dates looks like `d/m/Y`, not like US format `m/d/Y`: e.g. `29/01/2017`, which month is month 29?

Comment: Sorry, @HabibQadoos bit I am a bit surprised about this question. The answer I gave the last time you asked this question works perfectly fine. You confirmed that the code works and accepted it. Now you come back with a mixture between your old code and the suggested code again... May we know why you do _not_ use the solution I gave to you?

Comment: @arkasha Yes it works if the datetime is for the same month only. Like if all the values of datetime in the array are of same month. But if the datetime contains value of different month as sort them by date. As in the result you can see that it has sorted first the dates of january and then the dates of february.

Comment: Here are the dates and its timestamps.
29/01/2017 13:16 : 01/02/2017 20:15
1556709360 : 1483384500
As you can see that the timestamp of 29/01/2017 is greater than 01/02/2017 which is wrong and resulting in wrong date soring.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use usort() function with custom comarator:

```
$arr = array(...);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  $val1 = new DateTime($a['dateTime']);
  $val2= new DateTime($b['dateTime']);

  if ($val1 == $val2) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $val1 < $val2 ? -1 : 1;
});
```